# How to create a link to contact specific phone number via Telegram?

Tags: html, hyperlink, contacts, telegram, telegram-bot

So I found out I could use a link like this in HTML:

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone={{phone_number}}" target="_blank">WhatsApp</a>
```

in order to let a user contact `{{phone_number}}` directly from a webpage (via WhatsApp web).

My question is: how to do the same but instead of WhatsApp, via Telegram?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54258584/15247307
Why isn't this a limitation with WhatsApp?

Comment: Whatsapp doesn't respect users' privacy and allows governments to crawl and store user's data easily. That's one of the reasons authoritarian regimes such as Iran have blocked Telegram but not Whatsapp.

Answer (score 41):

#### Update (2022):

Links to phone numbers such as `https://t.me/+1XXXXXXX` will lead you to a web page the same as username links do, but you can only start chatting with the user if their privacy settings allows you.

#### Old answer:

It's NOT possible to link to Telegram like this for a phone numbers so far, because every user MUST add the phone number to their contact list before they can send a message to them by phone number. This limitation is because of Telegram privacy policy and abuse prevention. In more details, if Telegram allow this type of linking, a malicious party can fetch a web page like `https://t.me/+1XXXXXXX` for every possible number without passing authentication. That's most probably why Telegram doesn't have such linking feature.

However, you can link to `@username` of a Telegram user if he/she has any:

https://t.me/username

Comment: The answer seems to be outdated, because now https://t.me/+1XXXXXXX works fine

Comment: Pardon me, it works only for Telegram Desktop, but still not working for the app (((

Comment: @GeorgySpassky hey it does work on the mobile app as well

Answer (score 27):

You should create a link like https://telegram.me/YourUsername for that purpose.

Check [Telegram blog](https://telegram.org/blog/telegram-me-change-number-and-pfs) for more info.

Answer (score 15):

It is possible to create links to *Telegram*, *WhatsApp* and *Signal* accounts using their associated phone numbers using these URLs:

https://t.me/+41794997040
https://wa.me/+41794997040
https://signal.me/#p/+41794997040

Comment: Is it possible to also add a message there? Are there similar ones for video/audio calls via Telegram?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Not that I would know of 

Comment: Checking on the Contacts app by Google (when choosing a contact that has Telegram, and I have Telegram app), it seems that at least in the Android API it should be possible, but for some reason it doesn't work for me. Can you please see if I'm correct on this?

Comment: I've only looked at solutions that work cross-platform from a web-browser and not just within the ecosystem of a specific mobile OS, so I can't help you.