# How to open Telegram or Viber programmatically?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to open Telegram or Viber programmatically through a specific contact with message body? I found "how to open whatsapp": [whatsapp](https://mobikul.com/sending-message-application-whatsapp-number/). A similar solution may exist for Viber and Telegram!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Telegram, you can do three things:

- Open contact by url (https://t.me/usernameurl)

```
String user = "Telegram username";
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("https://t.me/"+user));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

- [The same but with the number doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54258584/9415337).
- Use [Telegram's bots api](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) (if it solved your question, but I don't think so).

Relating Viber you are also able to [do so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41324451/9415337). And, as with Telegram, you [can't search by number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50679437/9415337). The needed uri can be found here (according to [Viber](https://support.viber.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2856551-increase-the-reach-of-your-public-account)):

> Find your URI on your account's edit screen.

```
String user = "Viber public account uri";
String message = "Prefilled message"; // Not mandatory
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("viber://pa?chatURI="+user+"&text="+message));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```